# ActiveMQ JNDI/LDAP errors

Tags: ldap, jndi

Assume the following `jndi.properties`:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
java.naming.provider.url = ldap://localhost:389
java.naming.security.principal = cn=Directory Manager,dc=mycompany,dc=com
java.naming.security.credentials = ldap_password
java.naming.security.authentication = simple
```

Then, assume the `SimpleProducer` example in http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html. Because `cn=Directory Manager` contains a space, `jndiContext = new InitialContext();` fails with `javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]`. Even if you escape it as `cn=Directory\ Manager` or `cn=Directory\20Manager`.

If, however, you set the same inside the code, it works fine!

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Directory Manager,dc=mycompany,dc=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ldap_password");

try {
    jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);
} catch (NamingException e) {
   ...
}
```

Any ideas how to escape the space inside `java.naming.security.principal`? Or maybe, there is another thing that needs escaping? I also escaped the comma (,) without luck.

Then, assume that queues and topics are defined in LDAP, e.g.

```
dn: cn=q.ErrorReporting,ou=myproj,dc=mycompany,dc=com
javaReferenceAddress: #0#name#q.ErrorReporting
javaClassName: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue
javaFactory: org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory
cn: q.ErrorReporting
```

Then, when I set `destinationName ="cn=q.ErrorReporting,ou=myproj,dc=mycompany,dc=com"` the following code sets `destination="queue://null"`

```
try { 
   connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup(connectionFactory); 
   destination = (Destination)jndiContext.lookup(destinationName); 
} catch (NamingException e) { 
   LOG.info("JNDI API lookup failed: " + e); 
   System.exit(1); 
}
```

instead of actually finding the queue name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try enclosing the principal between quotes ? 
eg. `java.naming.security.principal = "cn=Directory Manager,dc=mycompany,dc=com"`

Comment: Of course; it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your queue name needs to be defined in LDAP in the following way:

```
javaReferenceAddress: #0#physicalName#q.ErrorReporting
```

`org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue` does not have `name` property but `physicalName`.